# ios-charts background color

Tags: swift, ios-charts

Hi would like to change the background color of my iOS-chart.

I tried:

```
barChartView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redcolor()
```

But it changed the color around my bargraph, not the color inside, ie. behind the vertical bars.

Any Idea?

Comment: Please provide more code on the creation of your Bar Chart

Answer (score 10, accepted):

barChartView.backgroundColor references the UIView of which your BarChartView is a subview.  You need to reference the base class of the BarChart itself to change the properties of the bars or the grid behind the bars.  To change the color of the space behind the bars try:

```
barChartView.gridBackgroundColor = UIColor.redcolor()
```

Comment: it would me great if u can explain the answer also for a easy understanding for another person having similar problem

Comment: You also need to write the following line of code: barChartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = true

Answer (score 8):

If Japes answer still does not work, make sure it's enabled.

```
barChartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = true
```

Comment: I don't know why this is down voted. By default drawGridBackgroundEnabled is false and setting its color does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Set grid background color
barChartView.gridBackgroundColor = UIColor.orange

// It is required to enable 'drawGridBackgroundColor' to see effect of gridBackground color 
barChartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = true
```